# makefile permission denied

Tags: makefile, permission-denied

I'm trying to make a C++ program that will find the shortest route out of the a maze. I'm struggling to get my makefile to work right now though. Currently, my makefile contains the following:

```
mazeIO : mazeIO.cpp maze.h
    g++ -g -Wall mazeIO.cpp maze.h -o mazeIO
```

mazeIO.cpp and maze.h are the only two files I have in the project. In the command line I am typing

```
make -f Makefile
```

and it compiles fine. Then I am typing

```
./mazeIO maze.txt
```

maze.txt is the maze input that I am trying to navigate.
After I type this in I get the following error:

```
bash: ./mazeIO: Permission denied
```

I do not understand why. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `ls -l mazeIO` show?

Comment: You don't need to list `maze.h` in the compilation line.  It looks like `g++` must ignore it; you're lucky.

Comment: ls -l mazeIO shows -rw------- 1 and then the directory I am in

Comment: Your umask seems broken, is my guess. `chmod 700 mazeIO` for first aid. What does `umask` print?

Answer (score 6):

This is simple.  It needs executable rights.

```
chmod +x mazeIO
```

You can also use chmod if it needs to be executed by other users.
`man chmod` will give you the numeric values needed if it needs to be executed by other users.  Be wary of giving full executable, read, and write rights (`chmod 777`)

`chmod 600` will not make it executable.

Answer (score 2):

Executable files are known as executable in Linux due to the presence of the execute (`x`) flag. Your "executable" doesn't have it - it only has the read (`r`) and write (`w`) permissions. Either you strip the permission from the executable (say, using `chmod 600 mazeIO`), or your umask is weird. umask controls the default user permissions on new files, and if you modified it from the default, it might wreak havoc. The default umask is `0022` for most systems, I suggest it be left there unless you know what will happen. I don't have any other idea why you might be missing the exec bit.

Comment: This would be more helpful if you provided a way of changing the umask setting.

Answer (score 0):

This does not fix the original question as stated, but I will share a possible solution for anyone seeing this same behavior (getting `bash: ./mazeIO: Permission denied`).

I was getting this error in a project because my Makefile was using the `-c` flag. This flag lets g++ compile and assemble project files but doesn’t link them, so the compiler creates a file that will appear to be the executable you are expecting but it is not actually an executable. The solution is to remove this flag.